# How to disable compact folder in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I drag folder2 into folder1 (which has no content) Visual Studio Code (VSC) will display the folders like so:

[image]

I like creating files in folders from the sidebar - but with this format, I don't know how to create files in folder1.

Does anyone have any work-arounds for this? Or, preferably, know to make VSC not display folders like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Click `folder1`, it will be underlined.
- If you now click the new file or new folder button it will create it in `folder1`

Answer (score 3):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `settings.json`
2. Paste `"explorer.compactFolders": false,`